# In SQL need to manually increment on Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which does not increment properly for ActionId

```
   insert into CorrAction (AlertId, Action, ActionId)

    select b.alertID,   a.Action, b.ActionId = (Select isnull(max(CorrectiveActionId),0) + 1 from CorrAction where alertid = b.alertId) 

    FROM 

    (select requestDate, action, tag from #alert ) a 

    INNER JOIN 

    (select alertdate, tag, alertId from #RetroAlert ) b 

    on Convert(date,a.requestdate) = Convert(date,b.alertdate) and a.tag = b.tag
```

The problem that I am having is that ActionId does not increment properly.

It should do something like the following:

```
AlertId    ActionId
------     --------
2344       1 
2344       2
3455       1
5344       1
3432       1
```

Notice that if there is a duplicate entry for AlertId, it should increment by 1. Else it should be 1.

What happens in my query is that is always remains at 1

Comment: you are not updating table CorrAction so you'll get the same number everytime

Comment: you better put another closing bracket around the value as (max(val, 0) + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.
Here is a simplified query because I don't know the structure of your tables.

```
SELECT
  AlertId,
  alertdate,
  (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(actionId), 0) FROM CorrAction AS c WHERE c.AlertId = t.AlertId) 
  + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AlertId ORDER BY alertdate DESC) AS ActionId
FROM TempTable AS t;
```

With an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d1d30/5

**EDIT:** Updated my example so that it starts counting from the highest actionId already inserted in the CorrAction table.

Answer (score 0):

Use row number function so below query should work

```
insert into CorrAction (AlertId, Action, ActionId)
select b.alertID,   a.Action,  row_number() Over  (partition by alertId  order by CorrectiveActionId) as ActionId
FROM 
(select requestDate, action, tag from #alert ) a 
INNER JOIN 
(select alertdate, tag, alertId from #RetroAlert ) b 
on Convert(date,a.requestdate) = Convert(date,b.alertdate) and a.tag = b.tag
inner join CorrAction C
on C.alertid =b.alertId
```